# Deleting files on QNAP NAS

Tags: 18.04, permissions, files, root, delete

I have some RARBG.COM.MP4 files on my Qnap Nas that I cannot delete even with changing the ownership, using root, etc. I even tried using the inode numberto delete them to no avail. How do I delete them?

```
$ ls -l
total 1541804 
-rw-rw---- 1 dragon dragon 1016764 Jan 11 2016 RARBG.COM.mp4 
-rw-rw---- 1 dragon dragon 34 Jan 11 2016 RARBG.COM.txt 
drwxrwxr-x 2 dragon dragon 0 Jan 11 2016 Subs 
-rw-rw---- 1 dragon dragon 1577778671 Jan 11 2016 The.Intern.2015.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.mp4 
-rw-rw---- 1 dragon dragon 4060 Jan 11 2016 
~:/sudo rm RARBG.COM.mp4
rm: cannot remove 'RARBG.COM.mp4': Permission denied
```

output of lsattr

```
-u--ia--cEjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
$lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4
s---i-d--EjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
$lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4
s-S-i----EjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
$ lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4
--S-ia--cEjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
$ lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4
--S--adA-EjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
$ lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4
-u--ia--cEjI------ RARBG.COM.mp4
```

So i did Sudo -i
the Sudo -i chattr 
get the below output...

Permission denied while setting flags on RARBG.COM.mp4

Comment: no it is  aread write filesystem

Comment: I can remove other files with the same names in different directories but there are a few that willnot be deleted

Comment: @Rinzwind done as requested.

Comment: Please add output of `lsattr RARBG.COM.mp4`

Comment: @Rinzwind output changes, not the same each time...

Comment: Does QNAP NAS run Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The file is set immutable.

To remove that flag, run:

```
sudo chattr -i RARBG.COM.mp4
```

OR login as `su` first, then run `chattr` (without `sudo`)

```
sudo -i
chattr -i RARBG.COM.mp4
```

Then you can delete the file.

See what all the other flags of that file mean: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html#ATTRIBUTES

Comment: I get this "sudo: setattr: command not found"

Comment: sorry, it must be `chattr`... (= change attributes)

Comment: I was about to say: its chattr ;) OH and he likely needs to  do `sudo -i`  and then on the  # do chattr.

Comment: output for chattr is "chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while setting flags on RARBG.COM.mp4"

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/324975/lsattr-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-while-reading-flags

Comment: @Rinzwind I think I confused `setfacl` and `chattr` ....

Comment: @AndreWeideman I think the issue with is not Ubuntu related, as QNAP Nas doesn't run Ubuntu ... ?!

Comment: mm. strange though I have deleted about ten other files with the same name from this QNAP with out any problems...there are about six left that won;t go away.

Comment: @Rinzwind I am an idiot...I just went and deleted them from the QNAP file manager...Thanks for your help